# java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column '*' cannot be null - Java Persistence - JPA - Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jackson, deserialization

I want to add a new Ticket to my SQL Database.
Ticket has 2 PK: event and code;

I created Entitys with Composite Keys and want to execute POST requests. I always get "Column 'seller' cannot be null". Anyone here knows how to work with **Java Persistence** and so on?

I tried it with IdClass and Embeddable but I get errors for both. It's just the inserting of a new Object in the Database. GET Requests work fine...
I tried different annotations but for now nothing worked. I probably don't really understand the concept of Java Persistence, but I also dont have to time to go trough it the whole way. So of it's obvious, please explain a little what it does... Thanks in advance!

My Entities:

Event.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="events")
@NamedQuery(name="Event.findAll", query="SELECT e FROM Event e")
public class Event implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String category;

    private String city;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date date;

    @Column(name="image_path")
    private String imagePath;

    private String name;

    private String venue;

    //bi-directional one-to-many association to Ticket
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="eventBean")
    @JsonManagedReference(value="eventBean")
    private List<Ticket> tickets;

    public Event() {
    }
```

Ticket.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tickets")
@IdClass(TicketPK.class)
//@NamedQuery(name="Ticket.findAll", query="SELECT t FROM Ticket t")
public class Ticket implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private long code;
    
    @Id
    private long event;

    private float price;

    private String type;
    
    //@Column(insertable=false, updatable=false)
    //private long event;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Event
    //One Event can have many tickets
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonBackReference(value="eventBean")
    @JoinColumn(name="event",nullable = false,insertable=false,updatable=false)
    private Event eventBean;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to User
    //One User can have many tickets
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonBackReference(value="seller")
    @JoinColumn(name="seller", referencedColumnName = "alias")
    private User user;

    public Ticket() {
    }
    
    public Ticket(long event, float price, Event eventBean, User user) {
        this.event = event;
        this.price = price;
        this.eventBean = eventBean;
        this.user = user;
    }

   //getters and setters
```

```
public class TicketPK implements Serializable {
    //default serial version id, required for serializable classes.
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    //@Basic
    //@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    //@Column(name="code", nullable=false)
    private long code;

    //@Basic
    //@Column(name="event",insertable=false)
    private long event;

    public TicketPK() {
    }
    
    public TicketPK(long code, long event) {
        this.code = code;
        this.event = event;
    }
    
//getters and setters

    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (this.equals(other)) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(other instanceof TicketPK)) {
            return false;
        }
        TicketPK castOther = (TicketPK)other;
        return 
            (this.code == castOther.code)
            && (this.event == castOther.event);
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int hash = 17;
        hash = hash * prime + ((int) (this.code ^ (this.code >>> 32)));
        hash = hash * prime + ((int) (this.event ^ (this.event >>> 32)));
        
        return hash;
    }


}
```

User.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
@NamedQuery(name="User.findAll", query="SELECT u FROM User u")
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private String alias;

    private String address;

    @Column(name="admin_status")
    private byte adminStatus;

    private String name;

    private String password;

    @Column(name="phone_number")
    private int phoneNumber;

    //bi-directional one-to-many association to Ticket
    //One User can have many Tickets
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
    @JsonManagedReference(value="seller")
    private List<Ticket> tickets;

    public User() {
    }
```

### DAO

TicketDAO

```
public interface TicketDAO extends CrudRepository<Ticket, TicketPK>{

    public List<Ticket> findAll();
}
```

### Controller

```
@Controller
@CrossOrigin
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    TicketDAO daoticket;
    
    /****************** OPERATIONS ON Tickets ************************************/

    
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/tickets", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Ticket> createTicket(@RequestBody Ticket ticket) {
        
        ResponseEntity<Ticket> response;
        
        Ticket newTicket = daoticket.save(ticket);
        if (newTicket == null) {
            response = new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_MODIFIED);
        } else {
            response = new ResponseEntity<>(newTicket, HttpStatus.CREATED);
        }
        return response;    
    }
}
```

### SQL Database

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `BD89_03_ticketsell`;
USE `BD89_03_ticketsell`;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `TICKETS`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `EVENTS`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `USERS`;

CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `name` varchar(100),
    `alias` varchar(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    `password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `address` varchar(100),
    `phone_number` int(10),
    `admin_status` boolean NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(`alias`)
);

CREATE TABLE `events`(
    `id` bigint NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `category` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `date` date NOT NULL,
    `city`varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `venue` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `image_path` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
);


CREATE TABLE `tickets`(
    `code` bigint NOT NULL,
    `event` bigint NOT NULL,
    `type` varchar(100),
    `price` FLOAT(10,2) NOT NULL,
    `seller` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(`code`, `event`),
    FOREIGN KEY(`seller`) REFERENCES `users`(`alias`),
    FOREIGN KEY(`event`) REFERENCES `events`(`id`)
);

INSERT INTO events (`name`, `category`, `date`, `city`, `venue`, `image_path`)
VALUES ('Cut Cupy', 'indie dance', '2024-01-22', 'Madrid', 'La Riviera', 'images/CUT-COPY2.png'),
('Dub Inc Tour 2022', 'reggae', '2021-05-03', 'Madrid', 'Sala Sol', 'images/DUB-INC-TOUR.jpg'),
('Kodaline', 'folk', '2022-03-15', 'Sevilla', 'Tablao el gitanillo', 'images/Kodaline.png');

INSERT INTO users (`name`,`alias`,`password`,`address`,`phone_number`, `admin_status`)
VALUES ('pepe', 'pepe', 'password', '17 Calle', '628791051', TRUE),
('pepe2', 'pepe2', 'password', '0 Calle', '628791052', FALSE),
('elisa', 'elisacool', 'contraseña', '3 Calle', '628791053', FALSE);

INSERT INTO tickets (`code`,`event`,`type`,`price`,`seller`)
VALUES ('1234', '1', 'palco', '17.5', 'pepe'),
('666666', '3', 'silla', '20', 'elisacool'),
('666666', '1', 'anfiteatro', '12', 'pepe2'),
('222222', '2', 'palco 3', '21.47', 'elisacool'),
('444666', '3', 'plató', '5', 'pepe'),
('111111', '2', 'palco 2', '40.99', 'elisacool');
```

### Console Error

```
2022-12-06 15:52:46.186  WARN 9656 --- [io-10303-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1048, SQLState: 23000
2022-12-06 15:52:46.186 ERROR 9656 --- [io-10303-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Column 'seller' cannot be null
2022-12-06 15:52:46.186  INFO 9656 --- [io-10303-exec-2] o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl     : HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
2022-12-06 15:52:46.199 ERROR 9656 --- [io-10303-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause


java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'seller' cannot be null
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:117) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:916) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31]
    
.
.
.
```

Comment: `seller varchar(100) NOT NULL`. What does your ticket look like before `daoticket.save(ticket);`? I assume that no seller is set

Comment: All the data in the database is set by the SQL Script. Or what do you mean with no seller is set? Where? I don't really know how Java persistence works... So how could I set a seller? 
->> I do not want to change the Database.

My POST contains: 
{
    "code": 14,
    "event": 132,
    "type": "dance",
    "price": 17.5,
    "seller": "pepe"
}

Comment: You have the seller ID in the JSON, but not the seller object, which is what you need to persist it correctly. Fetch the user from DB using the ID, call `ticket.setUser(sellerFromDB);` and only then `daoticket.save(ticket);`

Comment: Ok sound logic, thanks. 
So I would create a UserDAO Class to access the Database and fetch the User object or how would you do it?

Comment: I still don't understand how to access the ID (seller) in the JSON without loosing the other data. It should be possible without changing the Entitiy right? So if I set "@Responsebody Ticket ticket, I cannot access the ID because it is null and to set  "@Responsebody String json, and extract the String is not the way to do I guess...

Comment: Try serializing a java object that is 'correct' in the database to JSON. You need to make sure that the process is completely reversible or JPA will give you problems, and the JSON you are using isn't correct. JSON->Java must not be working for you and your 'user' property left as null. Try maybe sending an object: "user":{"alias":"pepe"} instead. Or make sure you send the seller "pepe" in the json some how so your parser can build it correctly.